# Order By Null among other values In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a result set of my Select Command which is :

```
1 Null Null Null
1 1    Null Null
1 1    Null 1
1 1    1    Null
```

But I need to reorder it like this:

```
1 Null Null Null
1 1    Null Null
1 1    1    Null
1 1    Null 1
```

How can I do that?

The SELECT statement:

```
 select K,
        Null As M,
        Null As T1,
        Null As T2,
        SUM(debit) SumDebit 
   from h 
        join i On h.HdrId = i.HdrIdRef 
        Group by K 

           Union 

 select K,
        M,
        Null As T1,
        Null As T2,
        SUM(debit) SumDebit 
    from h 
         join i On h.HdrId = i.HdrIdRef 
         Group by K,M 

             Union 
 Select * 
   From
       ( select K,
                M,
                T1,
                Null As T2,
                SUM(debit) SumDebit 
           from h 
                join i On h.HdrId = i.HdrIdRef 
                Group by K,M,T1
      ) A 
  Where A.T1 Is Not Null 

              Union 

 Select * 
  From
     ( select K,
              M,
              T1,
              T2,
              SUM(debit) SumDebit 
          from h 
               join i On h.HdrId = i.HdrIdRef 
               Group by K,M,T1,T2
     ) A 
 Where A.T2 Is Not Null 
       Order By K, M, T1, T2
```

Comment: What does your select statement look like?

Comment: What is the method of sorting?

Comment: select   K,Null As M,Null As T1,Null As T2,SUM(debit) SumDebit
from  h join  i On h.HdrId = i.HdrIdRef
Group by K
Union 
select   K,M,Null As T1,Null As T2,SUM(debit) SumDebit
from  h join  i On h.HdrId = i.HdrIdRef
Group by K,M
Union 
Select * From(
select   K,M,T1,Null As T2,SUM(debit) SumDebit
from  h join  i On h.HdrId = i.HdrIdRef
Group by K,M,T1)A
Where A.T1 Is Not Null
Union 
Select * From(
select   K,M,T1,T2,SUM(debit) SumDebit
from  h join  i On h.HdrId = i.HdrIdRef
Group by K,M,T1,T2)A
Where A.T2 Is Not Null
Order By K,M,T1,T2

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY ISNULL(Col4, 0), ISNULL(Col3, 0), ISNULL(Col2, 0), ISNULL(Col1, 0)
```

I'm assuming that you want the sort to start at the far right hand column based on your output